# How can I connect MongoDB which is running on Kubernetes cluster through UI tools like MongoDB Compass or RoboMongo?

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, mongodb-compass, robo3t

I have multiple instances of MongoDB deployed inside my Kubernetes cluster through [Helm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kubernetes#History) packages.
They are running as a service, in NodePort.

How do I connect to those MongoDB instances through UI tools like MongoDB Compass and RoboMongo from outside the cluster?

Answer (score 16):

You can use `kubectl port-forward` to connect to MongoDB from outside the cluster.

Run `kubectl port-forward name-of-a-mongodb-pod --namespace mongodb-namespace 27017:27017`.

Now point your UI tool to `localhost:27017` and `kubectl` will forward all connections to the pod/service inside the cluster.

Starting with Kubernetes 1.10+ you can also use this syntax to connect to a service (you don't have to find a pod name first):

`kubectl port-forward svc/mongodb-service-name 27017:27017 --namespace mongodb-namespace`

**Example**:

If your connectionstring looks like this:

`mongodb://username:password@mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/admin?replicaSet=mongodb&ssl=false`

1. Add the hostnames to you hosts file:

`127.0.0.1 mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local`

`127.0.0.1 mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local`

`127.0.0.1 mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local`

2. Use MongoDB Compass or Robo 3T and use the following connectionstring:

`mongodb://username:password@mongodb-0.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-1.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017,mongodb-2.mongodb-svc.mongodb.svc.cluster.local:27017/admin?replicaSet=mongodb&ssl=false`

Comment: Is this secure?

Answer (score 1):

Fetch the service associated with MongoDB:

`kubectl get services -n <namespace>`

Port forward using:

`kubectl port-forward service/<service_name> -n <namespace> 27018:27017`

Open Robomongo on `localhost:27018`.

Comment: Error `Exception opening socket Unknown host`

Answer (score 0):

If it is not your production database you can expose it through a NodePort service:

```sh
# find mongo pod name
kubectl get pods
kubectl expose pod <<pod name>> --type=NodePort
# find new mongo service
kubectl get services
```

Last command will output something like

```sh
mongodb-0   10.0.0.45    <nodes>       27017:32151/TCP   30s
```

Now you can access your mongo instance with `mongo <<node-ip>>:32151`

Comment: The qustion says "UI".

Answer (score 0):

If not resolved, expose your mongo workload as a load balancer and use the IP address provided by the service. Copy the LB IP address and use the same in the robo3T. If it requires authentication, check my YAML file below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
    name: mongodb
    labels:
        app: mongodb
spec:
    replicas: 1
    selector:
        matchLabels:
            app: mongodb
    template:
        metadata:
            labels:
                app: mongodb
        spec:
            containers:
                - name: mongodb
                  image: mongo
                  volumeMounts:
                      - name: data
                        mountPath: "/data/db"
                        subPath: "mongodb_data"
                  ports:
                      - containerPort: 27017
                        protocol: TCP
                  env:
                      - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_USERNAME
                        value: xxxx
                      - name: MONGO_INITDB_ROOT_PASSWORD
                        value: xxxx
            imagePullSecrets:
                - name: xxxx
            volumes:
                - name: data
                  persistentVolumeClaim:
                      claimName: xxx
```

Set the same values in the authentication tab in ROBO3T

*Note:* I haven't mentioned the service section in the YAML since I directly exposed as an LB in the GCP UI itself.

Comment: What is *"LB"*?